# Saying "for someone/something to" instead of "in order for someone/something to"

Tags: phrase-usage, grammaticality, phrase-choice

I have heard native English speakers say, *"for someone/something to"* instead of *"in order for someone/something to".* It sounds kind of informal to me and I feel like it might even be ungrammatical. Do you think it is fine to use it and it can be used in formal language?
Examples I made up:

> **You need to eat well for your muscles to grow.**

> **For my life to be settled, I transferred to another company.**

> **For things to get better, I keep myself hopeful.**

Comment: It's fine. It's not informal.

Comment: Your third example doesn't really make sense because it's not the same structure and meaning as the other two.  The first two are like "I do X for the purpose of accomplishing Y" but you wouldn't say "I keep myself hopeful **in order for** things to get better."